# Visual Studio 2008 Sample Macros

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there any place from where I can download the Visual Studio 2008 sample macros? 
It turned out that the folder VSMacros80\Samples is empty on my station.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, these aren't available online. (The closest thing I could find was the [Visual Studio 2005 Automation Samples](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=79C7E038-8768-4E1E-87AE-5BBBE3886DE8&displaylang=en), but I don't think this will give you want you are looking for.)

Have you tried a "repair" install? That might add them again.